# Простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми или два односоставных предложения?

Tags: грамматика, сказуемые, однородные-члены

Меня удивил ответ Грамоты.ру.

Вопрос № 305152
Здравствуйте, уважаемые сотрудники "Грамоты.ру"! У меня возник вопрос касательно одного предложения: ***Собираюсь выехать завтра и приеду к вечеру.***

Являются ли сказуемые однородными, или это определенно-личные односоставные предложения. Благодарю за ответ!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Это простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми.

Это действительное так? Я была уверена, что это односоставные предложения. Какой источник может подтвердить эту информацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласен с ответом Грамоты. Довольно простая ситуация.

*Я собираюсь выехать завтра и приеду к вечеру.* || Это просто предложение? Ну конечно!

А сейчас модно пропускать местоимения:
*Собираюсь выехать завтра и приеду к вечеру.* || Почему при отсутствии подлежащего предложение должно трансформироваться в сложное? Если были бы простые предложения в составе сложного, то было бы так:
*Собираюсь выехать завтра, и приеду к вечеру.*

Comment: Получается, что односоставных определенно-личных предложений вообще в природе не существует, если верить Грамоте и вам? "Пишу, читаю без лампады..."  – и всё такое.  И концовку вашу совершено не понимаю. Поставили запятую – и у вас простое предложение стало сложным? А модно сейчас пропускать местоимения в роли второстепенных членов, если вы об "информативной" моде.

Comment: Но в вашем примере односоставное определённо-личное, только одно, а не два. А вы что-то пытаетесь доказать, что в односоставном предложении не может быть более одного глагола. Где указано такое ограничение? А концовка равносильна следующему: *Собираюсь выехать завтра. И приеду к вечеру.* *Я была уверена, что это односоставные предложения* — **между предложениями должен стоять какой-то знак препинания**, если нет общего элемента, общей вопросительной/восклицательной интонации. В этом смысл концовки.

Comment: Собираюсь (хочу)  выехать  – составное глагольное сказуемое в первом односоставном предложении.  Приеду – простое глагольное сказуемое  во втором односоставном предложении. Односоставные предложения однородные, поэтому нет запятой. Да или нет?

Comment: *Односоставные предложения однородные, поэтому нет запятой* — если это сложное предложение (по-вашему), то запятая должна стоять, в определенно-личных предложениях всё решает то, одинаковый ли производитель действия (и у Розенталя об этом сказано). Мне кажется, что вы сделали неправильный вывод из того, что у Кустовой нет примеров с двумя глаголами. *Получается, что односоставных определенно-личных предложений вообще в природе не существует* — такого не говорил, односоставные предложения в составе сложного существуют: *Красивый закат, смотрю на него. Пришли домой, открыл дверь ключом.*

Comment: Это сложное предложение, но запятой в нем нет.  Вас это удивляет, это первый случай в вашей жизни? Знаете,  в сложных предложениях запятая не ставится между простыми односоставными предложениями, если они однородны и ПРИРАВНЕНЫ к однородным сказуемым. А общий производитель вычисляется по первому лицу (я). Всё! Пойду белок кормить!  Или уток, они такие дуси.

Comment: Да простое это предложение, потому что там один производитель действия. Что с подлежащим, что без него — простое. Наличие подлежащего на это не влияет!!!

Comment: Итак, как я считаю, дискуссия зашла тупик. Я должна вам на слово поверить, что это так?  Это в конце концов вопрос  ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЙ,  и решать его надо с привлечением соответствующей литературы. У Кустовой я нашла кое-что, но  там очень короткая и не до конца понятная информация. Поэтому предлагаю оставить вопрос ОТКРЫТЫМ, может, еще кто поучаствует в решении. Кстати, вот еще интересный пример: неоднородное определенно-личное предложение (один производитель, но разная форма сказуемого). Выезжай завтра, и утром будешь на месте.

Comment: У Кустовой: Односоставные предложения считаются простыми, если сочиненные сказуемые имеют ОБЩИЙ РАСПРОСТРАНИТЕЛЬ, например: Тебя здесь любят и помнят, ... Самому мне стало б вдруг невольно и стыдно, и смешно, и тягостно, и больно... (Полон.); ...В вершинах кленов и лип тревожно прошумело, потемнело и посвежело (Б.). стр. 112  https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf   Вам же спасибо за труды.

Comment: Мне не очень понятно, что значит "общий распространитель". Может, это "общий производитель". В предложении "*Выезжай завтра, и утром будешь на месте.*" сильное следствие, поэтому запятая. *Я должна вам на слово поверить, что это так?* — могу и доказать, но не люблю доказывать очевидное. Ладно... Предложения: *1) Мы зашли и ушли. 2) Мы зашли, и они ушли. 3) Зашли и ушли.* Из-за второго производителя действия в №2 нужна запятая. В №3 этот вариант не подходит, потому что ничто не указывает на второго производителя. Ещё может быть так: *4) Зашли, и они ушли.*

Comment: Общий распространитель - это общий элемент (тебя, мне, в вершинах). И речь идет только об односоставных предложениях, а вы приводите примеры с двусоставными предложениями. В общем, темная история, надо где-то еще читать.  У кыстовой получается для ЛЮБОГО вида односоставных предложений: есть общий элемент, значит, это однородные сказуемые в ПРОСТОМ предложении.

Comment: Вот такой интересный пример: *5) Они уже ушли? Да, мы зашли, и ушли.* Здесь контекст подсказывает, что ушли не те, кто зашёл. Но понятно, что так лучше не говорить из-за двусмысленности. Можно сделать вывод, что грамматическую основу образует подлежащее (король), не сказуемое (королева). Порой подлежащее может отсутствовать, но тогда используется обратный метод: подразумевается ли второе подлежащее, или все действия выполняются одним подлежащим. *а вы приводите...* — вам нужно сопоставлять односоставные и двусоставные, чтобы понять; метод изъятия слов помогает понять, на что они влияют.

Comment: *Общий распространитель - это общий элемент* — если так, то у Кустовой не совсем правильно сказано. Общий элемент, как известно, может связывать простые предложения (с разными производителями): *В вершинах кленов засверкало [молния] и зашумело [птицы испугались].* Чаще всего так и будет, как у сказано у Кустовой, но можно найти редкие исключения, потому что не это решающее, а количество производителей действия, это общий показатель для ССП.

Comment: Ладно, oleedd,  спасибо, так или иначе, но определенное мнение по этому вопросу у меня сложилось, хотя и не сразу. А это уже положительный результат. Поэтому я дам свой ответ, чтобы подвести итоги и закрыть тему. Ну а вам в качестве бонуса – принятие ответа, ведь вы изначально утверждали, что это простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми.

Answer (score 2):

1. При наличии в односоставных предложениях нескольких сказуемых и одиночных союзов И,ИЛИ часто приходится решать чисто практические вопросы: **это однородные сказуемые или сложное предложение,** нужно ли ставить запятую?
2. Углубляться **в грамматический анализ** в таких ситуациях не стоит – дело в том, что даже среди лингвистов здесь нет единой точки зрения, поэтому и обычным пользователям языка не надо этим заниматься.
3. Для практического решения задач **есть другие возможности**, а именно влияние **различных факторов**: (1) расчлененное или контактное расположение сказуемых,  (2) наличие собственных распространителей,  (3) описание одной или двух ситуаций, (4) наличие общего производителя действия,  (5) одинаковая или разная форма сказуемых.

Ну и конечно, **интонационная проверка**: расстановка пауз и логических ударений. Таким образом, подсказок более чем достаточно.

4. Важно отметить, что  выбор всех названных факторов часто зависит **от вида односоставного предложения:** определенно-личное, неопределенно-личное, обобщенно-личное, безличное, назывное.
5. А как же **грамматический анализ**, ведь даже в школьной практике требуется назвать вид предложения и объяснить постановку знаков. В этом случае  может помочь **цитата, взятая из вузовского учебника**:

«Односоставные предложения **считаются простыми**, если сочиненные сказуемые имеют ОБЩИЙ РАСПРОСТРАНИТЕЛЬ, например: **Тебя** здесь любят и помнят, ... **Самому мне** стало б вдруг невольно и стыдно, и смешно, и тягостно, и больно... (Полон.); ...**В вершинах кленов и лип** тревожно прошумело, потемнело и посвежело (Б.)»,  стр. 112  [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

6. Но о каком **общем распространителе** здесь говорится? Вероятно, в предложениях разного вида он будет различным. В частности,  для определенно-личных предложений достаточно того, что производитель обозначен как 1-е или 2-е лицо, что видно из формы глагола.
7. И вернемся к нашему предложению:  ***Собираюсь выехать завтра и приеду к вечеру.***

Это односоставное определенно-личное предложение,  производитель действия **определяется однозначно как 1-е лицо** (я). Соответственно,  другие факторы учитываться просто не будут (в частности,  разная форма сказуемых).

И здесь **явная интонация  простого предложения** с однородными сказуемыми, связанными одиночным союзом И, запятая не ставится.

Ну а для односоставных предложений другого вида решение будет иметь свои особенности.

Comment: Рад, что вы "перешли на сторону добра [истины]". Хороший у вас пункт 3, но там лишь (3) и (4) решающие, остальные — обычно (могут быть и исключения). Ну и (3) с (4) перекликается: разные производители — разные ситуации.

Comment: Ладно, oleedd, спасибо, подумаю еще над редакцией, пока пусть эта остается.   Здесь тщательность нужна,  тема, как вы видите, непростая...

Comment: Для меня простая, всё очевидно, даже и разбираться не пришлось :)

Comment: Ну да, сам себя не похвалишь, ведь никто не похвалит :))   И я  совсем забыла сказать, какой вы у нас молодец!  Вот сейчас говорю.

Comment: Не, ну честно, предыдущие ваши вопросы за этот год в основном простыми не были. Про поле было просто, вроде бы и всё.

Comment: Не, ну если честно,  Розенталь с Лопатиным односоставные предложения однородными членами не называли,  а вы вот взяли и назвали. Ну Грамота тоже, что с нее возьмешь.  Но  если бы Кустова к вам (с Грамотой)  не присоединилась. то вы бы меня еще долго уговаривали. Ну а в других учебниках кто-нибудь их так называет? Это же  такой шаг неординарный: были односоставные предложения - и вдруг в однородные  члены превратились. Каково, а!

Comment: А Розенталю и Лопатину главное — запятая, а не что как называется. Ответы Грамоты хорошие, вроде бы и не было таких, с которыми не был согласен. Да никто предложения однородными членами не называл, речь об однородных глаголах, которые просто присутствуют среди других частей речи. Началось моё вовлечение в это с ответа Eagle, которым вы были недовольны. Да ничего ни во что не превращалось, всё так и было изначально :)

Comment: Как же не превращаются, смотрите.   Стою. Думаю. Односоставные предложения? А теперь: Стою и думаю. Однородные сказуемые? Ну чем не фокус!  А Грамота ваша старорежимная, отстает от современной практики письма.

Comment: Это всё равно что: *Я стою. Я думаю. Я стою и думаю.* В одном предложении нет смысла повторять местоимение, как и дважды его подразумевать (что вообще бред).

Comment: Ну пот, начались подстановки – вернее, подставки. Каждое предложение индивидуально и имеет собственную грамматику. И не надо туда местоимения подсовывать!

Comment: Надо, как раз местоимения определяют, простое предложение или сложное.

Comment: Ну все, приехали...   Пора вас в чат, bye-bye.

Comment: Там нормально: если использовать @, то уведомления приходят.